# Passing a class object to another class error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class

I am working on a simple table view but I am having trouble passing a value as another class.

[image: Here is my class for each cell.]

Here is the class where I am initializing a cell as the class above.

[image: Here is the error I am getting.]

The identifier for table view cell in main.storyboard match with VideoTableViewCell class. I do not know why this error is here, any advice?

Comment: check build targets, delete derived data, clean the project and rebuild

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

1. check your VideoTableViewCell class target membership
2. try delete derived data
3. try clean the project and rebuild
4. try restart xcode

Answer (score 0):

Remove public in your function CellForRow in your VideoTableViewController. Or you can make VideoTableViewCell public too.